# How to get a json list from the curl in jenkins pipeline groovy script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Using curl in jenkins pipeline  script getting below json file , after that How to get the list values  of dependencies list and trigger those jobs?

```
{
  "Dependencies": [
    "Dep1",
    "Dep2",
    "Dep3"
  ]
 
}
```

My current program is looking like this which is not working. And after getting values I need to form the Jenkins jobs and trigger from pipeline

```
pipeline {
agent {
        label 'Dep-Demo'
    }
stages{
    stage('Getting Dependecies jason-object'){
            steps {
                script {
                    final String url = "https://***************/repository/files/sample.jason/raw?ref=main"
                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'api', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USELESS')]) {
                      sh ''' echo $PASSWORD ''' 

                      def response =  sh(script: "curl -s --header \"PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PASSWORD\" $url ", returnStdout:true)
                      echo "***** $response" 
                      def jsonObj = readJSON text: response.join(" ")
                      echo jsonObj
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example.

```
script {
    def jString = '''
            {
              "Dependencies": [
                "Dep1",
                "Dep2",
                "Dep3"
              ]
             
            }
        '''
        def jsonObj = readJSON text: jString
        jsonObj.Dependencies.each { dep -> 
            echo "Building ${dep}"
            //Building the Job
            build job: dep    
        }      
}
```